# Editing key inside array item - plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have the following plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Table 1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>subheadingArr</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>subheadingName</key>
                <string>Item 1 of table 1</string>
                <key>subheadingDetail</key>
                <string>Detail of item 1</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>subheadingName</key>
                <string>Item 2 of table 1</string>
                <key>subheadingDetail</key>
                <string>Detail of item 2</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>Table 2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>subheadingArr</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>subheadingDetail</key>
                <string>Item 1 of table 2</string>
                <key>subheadingName</key>
                <string>Detail of item 1</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>subHeadingDetail</key>
                <string>Item 2 of table 2</string>
                <key>subheadingName</key>
                <string>Detail of item 2</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am trying to write and read the

I have made these 2 methods trying to read and write `subheadingDetail` for a specific `subheadingName` but they are wrong/incomplete and can't manage to get it work.

```
-(void)updateInfo:(NSString *)info forSubHeadingName:(NSString *)subheadingName {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DeviceInformation.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    [data setObject:info forKey:subheadingName];

    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

-(NSString *)readInfoForSubHeadingName:(NSString *)subheadingName {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DeviceInformation.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    return [data objectForKey:subheadingDetail];
}
```

Tried searching around the answers, but couldn't find anything similar to my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by recursive traversing all dictionary and array. Bellow is sample code for solving your problem.

```
    -(void)updateInfo:(NSString *)info forSubHeadingName:(NSString *)subheadingName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DeviceInformation.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [self processAndSetObject:data parent:subheadingName Info:info];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

-(NSString *)readInfoForSubHeadingName:(NSString *)subheadingName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DeviceInformation.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    return [self processParsedObject:data parent:subheadingName];
}

-(void) processAndSetObject:(id)object parent:(NSString*)strKey Info:(NSString *)info
{
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        if([object objectForKey:@"subheadingName"] != nil)
        {
            if([[object valueForKey:@"subheadingName"] isEqualToString:strKey])
            {
                [object setValue:info forKeyPath:@"subheadingDetail"];
                return;
            }
        }
        for(NSString * key in [object allKeys])
        {
            id child = [object objectForKey:key];
            [self processAndSetObject:child parent:strKey Info:info];
        }
    }
    else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        for(id child in object)
        {
            [self processAndSetObject:child parent:strKey Info:info];
        }
    }
}

-(NSString *) processParsedObject:(id)object parent:(NSString*)strKey
{
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        if([object objectForKey:@"subheadingName"] != nil)
        {
            if([[object valueForKey:@"subheadingName"] isEqualToString:strKey])
            {
                return [object valueForKey:@"subheadingDetail"];
            }
        }
        for(NSString * key in [object allKeys])
        {
            id child = [object objectForKey:key];
            NSString *aStrRetVal = [self processParsedObject:child parent:strKey];
            if(aStrRetVal.length > 0)
            {
                return aStrRetVal;
            }
        }
    }
    else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        for(id child in object)
        {
            NSString *aStrRetVal = [self processParsedObject:child parent:strKey];
            if(aStrRetVal.length > 0)
            {
                return aStrRetVal;
            }
        }
    }

    return @"";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried it but for some reason i am not able to edit/read any info. Any idea why? :/

Comment: I have tested code with bellow command and it is working fine at my end. You can try and check for the same 

    NSLog(@"%@", [self readInfoForSubHeadingName:@"Item 1 of table 1"]);
    [self updateInfo:@"Test 1" forSubHeadingName:@"Item 1 of table 1"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self readInfoForSubHeadingName:@"Item 1 of table 1"]);
    [self updateInfo:@"details about item 1" forSubHeadingName:@"Item 1 of table 1"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self readInfoForSubHeadingName:@"Item 1 of table 1"]);

Comment: And one more thing is your file present in document directory or in application bundle if it is in application bundle than you have to make change as                                                                                       NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DeviceInformation" ofType:@"plist"];

Comment: Ughhh, you're right! sorry i thought i had the plist inside my document directory! Thanks a lot, it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a single object in Dictionary. you will again have to write complete plist.
For that you can do one thing. Fetch all the plist dictionary. Save it in dictionary object. Then edit detail whichever you wan't to edit. Then again write the complete dictionary to the plist with edited detail. This is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: I know that, that's why i am using `NSMutableDictionary` i am loading the plist inside it, edit it, and then save it back to plist file.
But my issue is that trying to edit `subheadingDetail` for an array item that include a specific `subHeadingName`.